# siunitx: \qty inside of two custom commands in \caption results in error

Tags: siunitx

I am using the command `\newcommand\emcpt[1]{{\bfseries #1}}` to emphasize the headings of my figures. I also created a command to facilitate using percentages `\newcommand\percent[1]{\qty{#1}{\percent}}` using the `siunitx` package. While both commands alone work well (and `\percent` in `\emcpt` in textmode too), using `\percent` inside of `\emcpt` inside of `\caption` results in the errors `! Argument of \percent has an extra }` and `! Paragraph ended before \percent was complete.` The formatting however is as expected. How can I get rid of the errors?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\newcommand\emcpt[1]{{\bfseries #1}}
\newcommand\percent[1]{\qty{#1}{\percent}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{\emcpt{Test: \percent{20} }}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In normal text, `\qty` does several local redefinitions of commands, including `\percent`.

However, the argument to `\caption` is a moving argument, meaning that your `\percent` will also be expanded when writing the text in the `.aux` file, but at that moment the valid definition of `\percent` is your own, so you get garbage.

Use `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Also I don't see a need to define `\emcpt` to do the same as `\textbf`. Better aliasing it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewCommandCopy{\emcpt}{\textbf}
\DeclareRobustCommand\percent[1]{\qty{#1}{\percent}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\caption{\emcpt{Test: \percent{20} }}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]